# Money Flow Integration with STRIPE

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripes

Using Stripe Top Up API to transfer money from Bank to Stripe Dashboard account and Stripe Transfer API to transfer those into connected account.

I have tried to Top Up directly on Stripe Dashboard and it was successfully created. When i tried with Top Up API it returns like this.[No Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvus6.png).

I also tried the source from Stripe Dashboard ( Which was created when i tried to top up directly from Stripe ) but its not working too. My project setting is for JPY (Japanese Yen ) so the testing token they provided on [Stripe Document](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#testing-top-ups) is not helping at all.[Stripe Testing Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvS1r.png). I also tried change **us **to **jpy **but not working as well [us To jpy token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaLpN.png).

Can someone explain to me how to use this Stripe Top Up API ? and how to attach the defauly payment like from card or bank into source too ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Top Up API : https://stripe.com/docs/api/topups does not work for Japan Stripe Accounts. You can only Top Up via the Dashboard.

Comment: thanks for your reply and Sorry for late response as well. Yes after 2 days, i have moved on researching [link] (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) `Charges Transfer`. I'm still not sure if it is the alternatives way for Top Up or not.

Comment: Charges and Transfers are not an alternative solution for Top Ups. At this point, I'd suggest that you reach out to Stripe Support for further advice since your questions are related to Stripe products, and not related to coding.